# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_ CIPHER_MISMATCH (Error)

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

[image]

Getting this error on Chrome Every-time Opening up this Website.
Actually, it's a screenshot sent to me by a friend living in the **US**

Though, it Opens up Smoothly here(*India*).

Comment: If it works for you and not for him you either use a different version of Chrome or there is something different with its network, like some firewall blocking or intercepting the connection. Since the site looks ok from here too I suggest that it is a network issue at your friends place.

Comment: look here
http://serverfault.com/questions/279984/clearning-chrome-ssl-cache

Answer (score -1):

For anyone having this error, try this:

Clear browser history (Ctrl+Shift+Del), at least the following parts:

Cached images and files
Hosted app data
Content licenses